# Screen corruption after hibernate — Is there another way to refresh the X11 display?

Tags: linux, xorg, desktop, desktop-environment, hibernate

When I restore from hibernate the screen is often corrupted. I suspect the graphics memory is not being saved. Suspend-to-ram works fine otherwise.

It also looks like the font-cache is corrupted, as all letters are corrupted consistently. The effect seems to target a font at a specific size. E.g. if my terminal window is hit, changing the font and/or the font size will fix it, unless that font with that size is already damaged.

If the font is used elsewhere (other apps, window manager, etc.), then the problem is there as well. Sometimes the font used for the window titles is hit, then all window titles show the same letters corrupted.

**Logging out and back in again fixes it**, but I don't want to have to do that. I have been logging-out then hibernating, but this is more effort and eliminates most of the benefit of hibernate.

**Is there another way to refresh the X11 display?** The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>… does not fix it either. It switches terminal but does not redraw anything: It just shows the old corrupted screen.

I am using Debian 6.

In this occasion the window title is bad:
[image: window title font deranged]

Terminal content bad, but title is (still) okay:
[image: text is distorted systematically, but only some fonts affected]

Comment: What graphics chip / driver are you using? Distro?

Comment: Debian 6, acer aspire 5338 integrated graphics. I have had it working in Ubuntu, and suspend to ram works excellent. I suspect it us just not saving graphics ram to disk.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question since that model seems to have been shipped with Intel, Nvidia, and ATI video card options. By "integrated" do you mean yours has the Intel GMA video card?

Comment: It's not clear from what you said - have you tried doing ctrl-alt-F1 _before_ hibernating (i.e. hibernating from text mode, and only switching back to X11 after resuming) ? you may need to find out the command to hibernate from the command line.

Comment: @Caleb: I have the same problem on an Thinkpad X200, Ubuntu 14.04, but packages from various releases, GM45 chipset with GMA 4500MHD, which is like X2500HD; x.org intel driver, intel_drv.so module version 2.99.910

Comment: @richard I approved Robert's edit since he seems to have the same issue. Please let me know if the screenshot does not correspond to the symptoms you have.

Comment: @Robert, have you attempted the `acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode` kernel option in my answer? It's suggested specifically for this `thinkpad_acpi` module.

Comment: I had the exact same thing on Debian 6, upgrading to Debian 7 and upgrading to the new kernel did the trick for me.

Comment: I have updated to debian7, it now works. @terdon the screen shots added to question, look similar to what I had.

Comment: Just to provide some additional information, the X Window System doesn't require that anybody anywhere "save graphics ram to disk." The X server and/or the video card can save the contents of **windows** to internal memory; this is called "save-behind." If save-behind is turned on, but it's not working properly, try using `xset` to turn it off and see what happens. This should force every app to redraw the screen on a refresh, unless the window manager is forcing save-behinds.

Comment: alias refresh_startx="xdotool keydown Alt key F2 keyup Alt key r key Return"

Comment: Why was the previous comment converted from an answer. What was wrong with then answer. OK it did not work, and is a bit short. But still it was an answer.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar situation with my laptop. The screen would often remain black when it woke from suspend. My solution was to use `xrandr` to reset my displays. You need to find the `xrandr` command that sets up your layout and run that. For example, on my system, I had two screens and this set it up as I wanted it:

```
xrandr --output DP-3 --auto --output VGA-0 --auto --right-of DP-3 --primary
```

If you only have a single screen, you could try switching it off and on again:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --off; xrandr --output VGA-1 --auto;
```

You can see the names of your screens by running `xrandr` with no arguments. On the system I am using now (one VGA screen), I get:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Once you find the right command, assign it a shortcut so you can run it even when the screen is blank.

Comment: I don't see how this could work. You get a black screen and have no interface...but you run a command? How? Doing alt+Fn won't work because even all X commands throw the error "Can't open display". Trying the `export DISPLAY=:0` trick just results in a different error.

Comment: @Cerin on my system, I've assigned a shortcut to that command so I can run it blindly by hitting Alt + F.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me (getting fancy screen glitches since I started using citrix receiver; that fixed it when all else failed). Note that if you run the command from a different VT on the same computer you may get a `Configure crtc 0 failed` error; just add a small sleep before the command and switch the VT so it's active when xrandr runs. @Cerin that's probably your issue. `sleep 5; xrandr --output VGA-1 --off; xrandr --output VGA-1 --auto`

Comment: Turns out that wasn't really my issue; when switching VTs it appears the windows manager or gnome shell catches up on events and remain unresponsive for some time; the time spent doing these actions was enough to catch up and refresh the screen. OTOH it did help once when I encountered a focus issue where I couldn't click on anything & and keyboard shortcuts were ignored - turning OFF then ON the display fixed it.

Comment: Is it normal for the above command (for one display) to leave you with a low-res (black) screen with the mouse pointer? If so how do I fix that?

Comment: @CoolCharac I guess you ran the command as it was in my answer? That was an example from my own system. The names of the attached screens will be different in yours. You need to figure out the `xrandr` command that sets your screens up the way you want them. Please read the rest of the answer and run `xrandr` with no arguments to see the names of your available displays.

Answer (score 10):

In **GNOME 3**, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> refreshes the GUI. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> launches the **Run Command** prompt, and the <kbd>r</kbd> command forces a refresh.

Comment: That sounds like you could also run `r` from the console. I have no `r` installed. – What should that run, you say? I.e. which package? What is the full name of that `r` program?

Comment: @RobertSiemer that's not a program, it's an internal GNOME thing that restarts the DE. I am guessing it runs `gnome --replace` in the background but I don't know.

Comment: `r` or `restart` (it's the same). The console equivalent would be `gnome-shell --replace`.

Comment: I run gnome-panel with metacity.

Comment: @richard, did this work?

Comment: This works for me in Debian Jessie and GNOME Shell 3.14.2.

Comment: Is there an xfce4 equivalent?

Comment: The LXDE and Lubuntu equivalents would be `nohup openbox-lxde --replace &` and `nohup openbox-lubuntu --replace &`, respectively.

Comment: Sure it works, but I lose everything I'm working on.  Might as well just shut down instead of suspend at that point.

Comment: @Julian, weird, nothing like that happened to me. What do you mean you lose everything you're working on? Do your open applications close, or is it something else?

Comment: @SeverynKozak, Yes, my open applications close.  Just tried it again and they didn't, so I don't know what happened.  But it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: An example of the problem: http://i.imgur.com/eDZdeaV.png

Comment: On ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome3, this solution works.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try the [`xrefresh`](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/xrefresh.1.xhtml) command?

Comment: Yes, did not work,

Comment: I will try that next time... FWIW most of the time I get a glitch affecting display, either switching between text and GUI VT's or using the switch user option (which locks one VT and unlock the other) fixes my issues... but on rare occasion it appears only xrandr can fix it. I normally switch VT's using `CTRL-ALT-F<n>` so I don't have to unlock all the time.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having this issue too (Debian Squeeze and Wheezy).

In my experience, it happens mainly when most of the memory is full and the system is using swap memory.

As a partial work-around: if I change the default fonts, the corruption goes away. (Not for good though, I have to change again when the corruption reappears.)

(On Debian Wheezy this is done by gnome-tweak-tool.)

Answer (score 4):

**Upgrade to Kernel 3.19.** – I used the [Ubuntu mainline kernel packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds), which can be found here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19-vivid/ (runs on Ubuntu 14.04 trusty as well)

The following bug report comment mentioned it

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45092#c37

...and tracked down the commit with the following message:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/656bfa3afc14e45e2d9e1624bf60d79b3beb12f2

“...since we've only ever seen this on gm45 and i965gm.”

I have that Intel GM45 mobile chipset with integrated graphics. The Acer laptop of the OP was also sold with that chipset (not all though).

(It had nothing to do with suspend.)

Answer (score 3):

If a driver is failing to resume a device properly, then I believe the only solution you will find will be in debugging and identifying where the problem is so you can decide what to do from there. For example, I don't see how you can refresh if the video card is not reinitialized.

**ACPI** handles suspend/resume and display. For example, the following ACPI issue that occurs on some ThinkPads may address the symptoms your are describing:

> When resuming from suspend-to-ram the text console displays may show
>   garbage instead of actual text. The machine is otherwise still
>   responsive and X displays fine. If all of this is true, then adding
>   the kernel option **acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode** in your *menu.lst* or
>   **lilo.conf** may solve the problem.

[Problems with ACPI suspend-to-ram - ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problems_with_ACPI_suspend-to-ram#Troubles_on_resume)

If you're using the `thinkpad_acpi` module that the above quote is addressing, that might be all you need. For more info on this solution, see [Suspend2Ram - Powersave Documentation](http://powersave.sourceforge.net/powersave/Suspend2Ram.html)

> First, there are several kernel parameters, that can be tried out.
>   Just add them to your "kernel"-line in **/boot/grub/menu.lst**. More
>   information about those can be found in
>   **/usr/src/linux/Documentation/power/video.txt**.

From video.txt:

> During S3 resume, hardware needs to be reinitialized. For most
>   devices, this is easy, and kernel driver knows how to do it.
>   Unfortunately there's one exception: video card. Those are usually
>   initialized by BIOS, and kernel does not have enough information to
>   boot video card. (Kernel usually does not even contain video card
>   driver -- vesafb and vgacon are widely used).

More at [video.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/video.txt) Refer to the table here to see if a known `acpi_sleep=<hack>` is listed for your video card model.

**Debian Suspend and KMS**
The Debian wiki suggests disabling KMS for a "corrupted video on resume" issue.[1](https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend#Fixing_corrupted_video_on_resume)

> A very common issue found after the computer resumes is corrupted
>   video (or black screen, or no LCD backlight). The first step is to
>   check whether the system is still running, which can be simply done by
>   pressing the Capslock button and check whether the Capslock LED is
>   changing accordingly. If the system is still running, in most cases we
>   need to add a video quirk for your video card.
>
> Debian now has kernel mode setting (KMS) enabled by default for most
>   Intel, nVidia and ATI video cards. But pm-utils' video quirk does [not]
>   support KMS yet. So in most cases you should try disabling KMS first.
>   The detail steps for your specific video card can be found on the
>   KernelModesetting page.
>
> After disabled KMS, if the video after resume still corrupts, you can
>   try to suspend the system by using some video quirks. Read the manpage
>   of the pm-suspend program for a very detail explanation of all the
>   quirks available, and try the combinations of them from commandline.
>   If you successfully find one combination of quirks that works for your
>   system, you can add them into /usr/lib/pm-utils/video-quirks to make
>   them permanent. At the same time, please help to file a bug against
>   the pm-utils package with a patch about your changes so it can benefit
>   the mass.
>
> A common issue found on systems upgrading from old versions of Debian
>   is the enabling of quirk-s3-bios freezes the system during suspend. If
>   your system freezes during suspend, check the pm-suspend.log carefully
>   after enabled debugging and make sure quirk-s3-bios is not used.

If you think this is related to your issue, you can try disabling KMS as suggested. For insructions for your card see [KernelModesetting - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting#Disabling_KMS)

**Debugging Suspend**

> The log of suspend and resume processes are in file
>   **/var/log/pm-suspend.log.** It contains moderately verbose information by
>   default. More information can be enabled for debugging by inserting
>   line **export PM_DEBUG=true** into the beginning of file
>   **/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions**.

For more, check out the info on Kernel testing facility mentioned at [Suspend - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend) as well. This can help you debug and isolate the problem.

Some examples and more in-depth debugging info that may help you "drivers that fail to suspend or resume their devices" is available at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt

Some more debugging ideas for `pm-utils` at [pm-utils - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pm-utils) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29090/87728

Here's a full list of [Kernel Parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) many being relevant to acpi and suspend.

Good luck.

Comment: X display is not fine; virtual text terminals are fine

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`? Did you enable debugging in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions` and check it after that?

Comment: You can test suspend with quirks from the terminal using `pm-suspend --quirk-s3-bios --quirk-s3-mode`. See the options section in `man pm-action`.

Comment: I checked `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`. Nothing unusual. I’m using KMS. – Disabling KMS is no option these days (xorg intel driver needs it); that wiki you pointed to was last updated 2012.

Comment: Just want to say that `dmesg | tail -50` command can be useful for debugging. I actually discovered low memory corruption related to suspend that I was able to resolve with kernel parameters in grub `memmap=64K$0 memory_corruption_check=0`. I believe it will tell you if there is an error initializing the video card.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a reported bug, check the link that follows.

In case of **Ubuntu** check [this link](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/659434)

In case of **Debian** read [this other link](http://wiki.debian.org/Suspend) specially the **Fixing corrupted video on resume** part

In case the problem is in a text console:
Have you tried refreshing the fonts cache?

`fc-cache -f -v`

Comment: Does not help...

Comment: This seems to be a reported bug, check the link that follows. If your distro is not Ubuntu, the bug may not be specific to a distro but some libraries that may affect other distros. Dig into the bug/s and see if it is solved for your distro...  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/659434

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your distro was Debian. Check the next link: https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend specially the **Fixing corrupted video on resume** part.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: OK, question stated "I am using Debian 6." before the first screenshot. Then I guess you will find your answer in launchpad's bugs... Anyway, Ubuntu is based on Debian so maybe a solution from the Debian's link can help you out.

Comment: @richard is the OP, but somehow abandoned his question a little... – And so far I really believe we have the same problem. – I would love to hear if he can confirm what he sees on the screenshots.

Comment: That launchpad bug report was a hot tip! In my case it turned out that the kernel DRM needs an extra quirk for the GM45 mobile chipset graphics. https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45092#c37  Kernel 3.19 packaged (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19-vivid/) seems to do the trick. – I have to test some days.

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because the graphics driver has bugs for the display device.  It probably won't matter too much which it is, because either way it's not something you can likely fix.  But you should file a bug about the kernel driver for the device (once you figure out what it is (`lspci` may help here)).

Something you could try, though, as a work around: when coming out of hibernate, try hitting "ctrl-alt-F4" to switch to another virtual terminal and then switching back (which is likely either ctrl-alt-F1 or ctrl-alt-F7 or maybe F8).  This may do enough of a screen refresh that it'll make the display recover.  Maybe.

Comment: have tried ctrl-alt-F1 it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try rotating or flipping your screen with [`xrandr`](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.xhtml), e.g. upside-down and then back to normal. This might be enough to have it fully redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

> The Ctrl+Alt+F1… does not work

Well… then try issuing `sudo chvt 1`, then switch back to Xorg's vty using Ctrl_Alt_Fn or `sudo chvt N` (where N is usually 7 or 8). In case `chvt` would work, you can even try scripting it.

Comment: sorry I was not clear ctrl+alt+f1 works. It is the ctrl+alt+f1 solution that does not. I can switch virtual terminals, but it does not fix the corruption. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> then <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>. That changes the screen resolution back and forth.

Comment: nothing. May be the keys are not bound.