# My laptop is not able to recover from suspend and hibernate

Tags: ubuntu, suspend, hibernate

I have a acer aspire 5750G laptop. I am running ubuntu 11.04.

The `uname -a` reads the following:

> Linux admin-Aspire-5750G 2.6.38-13-generic-pae #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 14     14:32:30 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Whenever the wakes up from suspend or hibernate, it shows a blank screen. Same thing happens when the lid is closed and opened later. What should I do to fix this?

**Edit#1:** I have the `pm-utils` installed. I could suspend using `pm-suspend`. When I press any key to wake up, the machine wakes up but hangs. It does not respond to any keyboard or mouse keys after wake up. What could be wrong here?

Comment: [*"How to debug a suspend problem?"*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28097/11539)

Comment: @sr_: I have the pm-utils installed. I could suspend using pm-suspend. When I press any key to wake up, the machine wakes up but hangs. It does not respond to any keyboard or mouse keys. What could be wrong here?

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29447/11539) mentions [an Ubuntu Wiki article on debugging a failing resume](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend).

Comment: @sr_: Thanks for the directions. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar issue in Debian 9, installed on a **Lenovo G40-30 Laptop**. I went into Hibernate/Sleep 
and trying to initiate again the screen didn't show up although everything seemed working.

The solution is actually quite simple. It seems Linux OSs, in particular Debian and Ubuntu need at least a **4+GB swap partition** for Hibernate/Sleep to work properly. If you installed with "default" configuration it 
will create a Swap the same size of your actual RAM (in practice a little less). So if you have a laptop with less or equal to 4 Gb RAM and installed "default" configuration, you are probably trying to solve this issue.

Swap allocation in Linux work in two ways:

1) in the form of a SWAP PARTITION in your hardrive.

2) in the form of a SWAP FILE.

YOU CAN CREATE THE `SWAP` FILE AS FOLLOWS:

```
sudo swapon --show
```

shows if you have enabled the swap option. If not look up how to do this.

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
```

sets the size of the swap you add to 1Gb,                               change to the value you need.

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile        # sets the file to be owned by root     
sudo mkswap /swapfile           # mkswap tool to allocate swap in the file
sudo swapon /swapfile           # activate the swap 
sudo nano /etc/fstab            # open the file to make changes permanent
```

Add the line `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0` to the file `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo swapon --show              # show if its working
sudo free -h                    # show Memory and Swap
```

IF YOU WANT TO UNDO CHANGES JUST:

```
sudo swapoff -v /swapfile
```

remove the line from `/etc/fstab` file:  `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0`

```
sudo rm /swapfile         # remove the swap file
```

SWAP SIZES ACCORDING TO RAM:

I can indicate the following table with some recommended 
`SWAP` sizes according to your RAM. Last 3 columns are `SWAP` spaces:

```
    RAM       No hibernation    With Hibernation   Maximum

    1GB              1GB                 2GB        2GB
    2GB              1GB                 3GB        4GB
    3GB              2GB                 5GB        6GB
    4GB              2GB                 6GB        8GB
    5GB              2GB                 7GB       10GB
    6GB              2GB                 8GB       12GB
    8GB              3GB                11GB       16GB
   12GB              3GB                15GB       24GB
   16GB              4GB                20GB       32GB
   24GB              5GB                29GB       48GB
   32GB              6GB                38GB       64GB
   64GB              8GB                72GB      128GB
  128GB             11GB               139GB      256GB
  256GB             16GB               272GB      512GB
  512GB             23GB               535GB        1TB
    1TB             32GB              1056GB        2TB
    2TB             46GB              2094GB        4TB
    4TB             64GB              4160GB        8TB
    8TB             91GB              8283GB       16TB
```

MORE INFORMATION:

you can find thorough information on recommended SWAP sizes according to your RAM in the following link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-8tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher

Credit is due for the table I added here.

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem, which is resume from suspend/hibernate.