# Computer doesn't wake from sleep mode

Tags: slackware, sleep

I have a laptop with Linux Slackware 14, KDE 4.8.5, kernel 3.9.0-rc6. When I close the lid and pull out the power cord, the machine goes into sleep mode. When I wake it, plugging the cord back in and opening the lid, the LEDs turn on, but the screen doesn't. The system responds via ssh. Maybe, it's Intel video driver?

What is going on? How can I fix it?

#### EDIT #1

Here is some additional info regarding my system:

- [/var/log/pm-suspend.log](http://pastebin.com/ha72ZrYd)
- [/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video](http://pastebin.com/st6n3D4i)

Here's info about my video card:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor   
Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

#### EDIT #2

Looking at the output in the log `pm-suspend.log` there is mention of an illegal instruction at line #48 of the `99video` script. Here are the contents of that section of the script:

```
reset_brightness()
{
        for bl in /sys/class/backlight/* ; do
                [ -f "$bl/brightness" ] || continue
                BR="$(cat $bl/brightness)"
                echo 0 > "$bl/brightness"
                echo "$BR" > "$bl/brightness"
        done
}
```

Comment: @slm question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Here are the instructions:

1.
 I didn't have the swap - as I had 4 Gb of RAM. But swap is necessary for suspend mode. So I had to create a swap file of 4 Gb, using the instructions here:
[www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/)

2
. Removed `nomodeset` kernel param from lilo.conf

Answer (score 2):

Debugging this type of issue can be tricky. I would first start with trying to manually force it into suspend mode with the following command:

```
PM_DEBUG=true pm-suspend
```

Then check `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` for hints on what might be going wrong. Perhaps something is going wrong during suspend mode.

Here's a good article on the [Ubuntu wiki on how to debug this resumes from suspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend).

#### Diagnosing PCI Bus of Video Card

On my laptop:

```
% lspci -v
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 215a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

The address 00:02.0 corresponds to:

```
% ls "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/"
boot_vga                  drm/                      i2c-5/                    remove                    rom
broken_parity_status      enable                    irq                       rescan                    subsystem/
class                     firmware_node/            local_cpulist             reset                     subsystem_device
config                    graphics/                 local_cpus                resource                  subsystem_vendor
consistent_dma_mask_bits  i2c-0/                    modalias                  resource0                 uevent
device                    i2c-1/                    msi_bus                   resource2                 vendor
dma_mask_bits             i2c-2/                    numa_node                 resource2_wc              
driver/                   i2c-4/                    power/
```

To turn on the power control:

**See what it's set to**

```
% cat "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control" 
auto
```

**Set it to on**

```
% echo "on" > "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control"
```

#### References

- [How to Debug Suspend Mode Problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28097/how-to-debug-a-suspend-problem)
- [OpenSUSE: SDB:Pm-utils](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Pm-utils)
- [OpenSUSE: SDB:Suspend_To_RAM](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Suspend_to_RAM)
- [Thread: Cannot wake laptop after suspend](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/480867-cannot-wake-laptop-after-suspend.html)

Comment: I was wrong: the system responds through ssh. iptables were blocking. I got the log, but I don't know, what to search there - it's big.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iq5Q8CXz

Comment: In this thread https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=158751&p=2 the guy said, that he enabled the screen by sending data into the file: `echo on > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:19.0/power/control`. How can I find, which file  to use: I don't have this dir.

Comment: cat "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control" gives `on` to me

Comment: both give `Illegal instruction` output. echo 'on' to `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control`  also doesn't change anything.

Comment: xset dpms force off -> `xset:  unable to open display ""` Can you come to chat?

Comment: haha: `xset:  unable to open display ":0.0"`

Comment: One more thing to try: XAUTHORITY=/home/$YOURUSER/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0.0 xset dpms force off. You need the XAUTHORITY variable and the DISPLAY variable for xset to work I believe.

Comment: Let's clean up the comments!

Comment: I am working as root there. Does it change anything about XAUTHORITY?

Comment: Point to whatever user you use to login to the desktop. That's the .Xauthority file you need to have access to.

Comment: I think, that this won't help. Because I didn't have X started on my system when I suspended. Of course, xset can't find the display.