# XUbuntu 14.04 - Why does my XFCE panel (xfce4-panel) become corrupted after sleep/suspend is resumed?

Tags: xfce, session, xubuntu, hibernate, panel

I am having a problem with my laptop (HP Elitebook 8570w) -- whenever I close the screen and it goes into sleep/suspend/hibernation mode (take your pick on the name of this feature).  When I reopen the laptop lid and the session comes back up, everything is fine **EXCEPT** that the xfce4-panel does not draw correctly (it will be either all black, or will have artifacts of whatever previously drew on that area of the screen).

The panel still functions when you click buttons, but they no longer draw/update.  Any other graphical elements get 'drawn over' it and the panel becomes very difficult to use.  The best way to describe it is 'graphical corruption' or perhaps 'artifacts' - but thus far I've been unsuccessful in seeing anyone else online describe exactly the same problem I'm having.

I have tried restarting the xfce4-panel process, but it results in the same thing again.  I have tried restarting some other xfce processes, and also tried `xrefresh` among other things but to no avail.  The only way I can get rid of it is to log out and log back in, but I lose all my windows and stuff and it's extremely annoying.  I run a VMWare VM and a bunch of other stuff which I want to keep in the memory state to be restored when I come back from suspend/hibernation state.

Is there perhaps some other process(es) I can restart to restore my panel without logging all the way out and losing my session?

Any insight into this problem would be very much appreciated, even if it's some kind of workaround. Thanks!

**ADDITIONAL INFO -**

Notes:

- Discovered that when i use Printscreen to take a screenshot, the draw call comes through ONCE and refreshes the panel and the existing artifacts are removed (hence I can't even take a screenshot of the artifacts happening) But it still won't continue to update after that.  Simply hovering over any 'window button' area will open a tooltip with the full name of the window which will overwrite the panel area and be stuck there until some other graphical element overwrites it.

**Graphics**:

```
Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Chelsea XT GL [FirePro M4000] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
X.Org: 1.15.1 driver: fglrx Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz, 3840x1080@59.9hz, 3840x1080@59.9hz 
GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 7700M Series GLX Version: 4.3.12798 - CPC FireGL 13.35.1005 
Direct Rendering: Yes
Driver: fglrx-updates (proprietary AMD/ATI driver)
```

Seemingly notable entries in **/var/log/pm-suspend.log** :

```
...

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

...


 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
ATI Catalyst driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Tue Apr  7 19:20:51 MST 2015: performing suspend
```

** THIS IS WHEN THE LAPTOP GOES TO SUSPEND MODE **
  ** NOW I OPEN THE LID AND PRESS POWER TO WAKE UP **

```
Tue Apr  7 19:21:16 MST 2015: Awake.
Tue Apr  7 19:21:16 MST 2015: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

...

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.
```

Here is the **full output** from the log:

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Tue Apr  7 19:20:49 MST 2015: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux ad-work 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
vmnet                  51277  13 
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport    26278  0 
vsock                  34903  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vmw_vmci               62966  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vmmon                  76182  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  12 
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
arc4                   12608  2 
iwldvm                232285  0 
mac80211              630669  1 iwldvm
btusb                  32412  0 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
bluetooth             391136  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
pl2303                 19133  0 
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
usbserial              45014  1 pl2303
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
hp_wmi                 14062  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      54762  1 
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             143187  0 
kvm                   455835  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
aesni_intel            55624  0 
snd_hda_intel          56531  11 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_pcm               102099  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
joydev                 17381  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              13462  0 
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lpc_ich                21080  0 
fglrx                8081247  124 
snd                    69322  32 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
soundcore              12680  1 snd
amd_iommu_v2           19054  1 fglrx
video                  19476  0 
parport_pc             32701  1 
hp_accel               26012  0 
tpm_infineon           17372  0 
lis3lv02d              20156  1 hp_accel
wmi                    19177  1 hp_wmi
ppdev                  17671  0 
input_polldev          13896  1 lis3lv02d
shpchp                 37032  0 
hp_wireless            12637  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 52659  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
psmouse               106714  0 
firewire_ohci          40409  0 
e1000e                254433  0 
ahci                   29915  2 
firewire_core          68769  1 firewire_ohci
sdhci_pci              23172  0 
libahci                32716  1 ahci
sdhci                  43015  1 sdhci_pci
ptp                    18933  1 e1000e
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
pps_core               19382  1 ptp
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16364188    9371636    6992552      65936     202812    5697516
-/+ buffers/cache:    3471308   12892880
Swap:     16705532          0   16705532
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
stop: Unknown instance: 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
ATI Catalyst driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Tue Apr  7 19:20:51 MST 2015: performing suspend
Tue Apr  7 19:21:16 MST 2015: Awake.
Tue Apr  7 19:21:16 MST 2015: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254

/dev/sdb:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

Tue Apr  7 19:21:17 MST 2015: Finished.
```

When I kill xfce4-panel and restart to look at debug output. Commands:

```
xfce4-panel -q
PANEL_DEBUG=1 xfce4-panel
```

(nothing appears out of the ordinary):

```
xfce4-panel(main): version 4.11.0 on gtk+ 2.24.23 (2.24.22), glib 2.40.2 (2.39.90)
xfce4-panel(module-factory): reading /usr/share/xfce4/panel/plugins
xfce4-panel(module-factory): reading /usr/share/xfce4/panel-plugins
xfce4-panel(application): found window manager after 1 tries
xfce4-panel(base-window): 0x7ff7c204c1e0: rgba colormap=0x7ff7c2038250, compositing=false
xfce4-panel(base-window): 0x7ff7c204c1e0: rgba colormap=0x7ff7c2038250, compositing=false
xfce4-panel(display-layout): 0x7ff7c204c1e0: display=:0.0{comp=true}, screen-0[0x7ff7c201c000]=[5760,1080] (DFP1=[0,0;1920,1080], DFP_=[1920,0;1920,1080], LVDS=[3840,0;1920,1080])
xfce4-panel(positioning): 0x7ff7c204c1e0: screen=0x7ff7c201c000, monitors=3, output-name=(null), span-monitors=false, base=960,1067
xfce4-panel(positioning): 0x7ff7c204c1e0: working-area: screen=0x7ff7c201c000, x=0, y=0, w=1920, h=1080
xfce4-panel(struts): 0x7ff7c204c1e0: bottom=25, start_x=0, end_x=1919
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/1
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=whiskermenu, id=1)
xfce4-panel(external): whiskermenu-1: child spawned; pid=15768, argc=8
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=tasklist, id=2)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=separator, id=3)
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/4
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=systray, id=4)
xfce4-panel(external): systray-4: child spawned; pid=15770, argc=8
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/5
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=indicator, id=5)
xfce4-panel(external): indicator-5: child spawned; pid=15771, argc=8
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=separator, id=6)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=clock, id=7)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=showdesktop, id=8)
xfce4-panel(systray): registered manager on screen 0
xfce4-panel(external): systray-4: child is embedded; 5 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): whiskermenu-1: child is embedded; 5 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): indicator-5: child is embedded; 5 properties in queue
```

And one more thing, I tried xfce4-panel with debug enabled on the `module` debug channel using `PANEL_DEBUG=module xfce4-panel`.  I'm not sure if this is the right channel, but it did have some more interesting output:

```
xfce4-panel(main): version 4.11.0 on gtk+ 2.24.23 (2.24.22), glib 2.40.2 (2.39.90)
xfce4-panel(module-factory): reading /usr/share/xfce4/panel/plugins
xfce4-panel(module): new module tasklist, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libtasklist.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module separator, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libseparator.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module xfce4-mount-plugin, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libmount.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module actions, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libactions.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module systemload, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libsystemload.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module genmon, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libgenmon.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module launcher, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/liblauncher.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module datetime, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libdatetime.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module screenshooter, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libscreenshooterplugin.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module xfce4-clipman-plugin, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libclipman.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module weather, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libweather.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module mailwatch, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libmailwatch.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module windowmenu, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libwindowmenu.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module battery, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libbattery.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module pager, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libpager.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module clock, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libclock.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module whiskermenu, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libwhiskermenu.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module xfce4-dict-plugin, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libxfce4dict.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module indicator, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libindicator-plugin.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module systray, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libsystray.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module smartbookmark, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libsmartbookmark.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module wavelan, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libwavelan.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module fsguard, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libfsguard.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module applicationsmenu, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libapplicationsmenu.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module cpugraph, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libcpugraph.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module directorymenu, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libdirectorymenu.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module showdesktop, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libshowdesktop.so, internal=true
xfce4-panel(module): new module mixer, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libmixer.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module diskperf, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libdiskperf.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module cpufreq, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libcpufreq.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module places, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libplaces.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module-factory): reading /usr/share/xfce4/panel-plugins
xfce4-panel(module): new module xfce4-orageclock-plugin, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-orageclock-plugin, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module quicklauncher, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/libquicklauncher.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module xfce4-notes-plugin, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/libnotes.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module xkb-plugin, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module thunar-tpa, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libthunar-tpa.so, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module netload, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-netload-plugin, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module xfce4-verve-plugin, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-verve-plugin, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module xfce4-sensors-plugin, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-sensors-plugin, internal=false
xfce4-panel(module): new module xfce4-timer, filename=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-timer, internal=false
xfce4-panel(application): found window manager after 1 tries
xfce4-panel(base-window): 0x7fa9dc1f61e0: rgba colormap=0x7fa9dc1e2250, compositing=false
xfce4-panel(base-window): 0x7fa9dc1f61e0: rgba colormap=0x7fa9dc1e2250, compositing=false
xfce4-panel(display-layout): 0x7fa9dc1f61e0: display=:0.0{comp=true}, screen-0[0x7fa9dc1c4b60]=[5760,1080] (DFP1=[0,0;1920,1080], DFP_=[1920,0;1920,1080], LVDS=[3840,0;1920,1080])
xfce4-panel(positioning): 0x7fa9dc1f61e0: screen=0x7fa9dc1c4b60, monitors=3, output-name=(null), span-monitors=false, base=960,1067
xfce4-panel(positioning): 0x7fa9dc1f61e0: working-area: screen=0x7fa9dc1c4b60, x=0, y=0, w=1920, h=1080
xfce4-panel(struts): 0x7fa9dc1f61e0: bottom=25, start_x=0, end_x=1919
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/1
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=whiskermenu, id=1)
xfce4-panel(external): whiskermenu-1: child spawned; pid=16362, argc=8
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=tasklist, id=2)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=separator, id=3)
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/4
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=systray, id=4)
xfce4-panel(external): systray-4: child spawned; pid=16364, argc=8
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/5
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=indicator, id=5)
xfce4-panel(external): indicator-5: child spawned; pid=16365, argc=8
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=separator, id=6)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=clock, id=7)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=showdesktop, id=8)
xfce4-panel(systray): registered manager on screen 0
xfce4-panel(external): whiskermenu-1: child is embedded; 5 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): systray-4: child is embedded; 5 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): indicator-5: child is embedded; 5 properties in queue
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-messages main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-application main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-messages main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-sound main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-application main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-messages respawning too fast, stopped
init: indicator-application respawning too fast, stopped
init: indicator-sound main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-sound respawning too fast, stopped
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-power respawning too fast, stopped
```

Comment: currently investigating a somewhat similar looking issue here:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14494/screen-corruption-after-hibernate-is-there-another-way-to-refresh-the-x11-disp?rq=1

Comment: went ahead and filed a bug on xfce bugzilla.  on the bug report i attached a screenshot of the panel corruption:

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11802

Comment: there's been no response on this problem, unfortunately.  i did find one sort-of workaround which is to use `killall xfce4-panel` before I close the laptop to go to suspend, then I created a desktop shortcut which reopens the panel when I resume my session.  Maybe there's a way to automatically have the system do this before it goes into suspend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only post I have seen mentioning this specific issue. I also had the problem with the corruption of the XFCE panel in Xubuntu 14.04 after suspending by closing the lid of my laptop. Once I opened the lid, the panel was always corrupted - often just black. The desktop looked OK but if I opened files, the various buttons to maximise etc were missing too.

If I suspended the laptop via the Log Out menu, there was no problem. Everything came back perfectly.

After a bit of pondering, I came up with the idea of re-enabling the Compositing option for the desktop which I had disabled to save memory. And enabling compositing solved the corruption issues for me. Simple.

My laptop is also a HP (different model though) although I am not sure if the problem is HP specific.

Hope this might help someone.